# Azure OpenAI and load balancer configuration using APIM

Tags: python, azure-api-management, azure-load-balancer, azure-openai

I was experimenting with Azure OpenAI and load balancer configurations using API management. I have a basic web app with a front end that takes input and summarizes the text.

I have configured my load balancer policy with my openai endpoints and also configured APIM accordingly.

The place where I am stuck is the python configuration with the APIM and load balancer endpoints and how to use them. Earlier I used the OpenAI endpoint directly with the key but now i feel things would change just not sure how to change them.

Would be extremely grateful if someone can help me out here. Thanks

Below is the policy :

'''

```
<!--
    IMPORTANT:
    - Policy elements can appear only within the <inbound>, <outbound>, <backend> section elements.
    - To apply a policy to the incoming request (before it is forwarded to the backend service), place a corresponding policy element within the <inbound> section element.
    - To apply a policy to the outgoing response (before it is sent back to the caller), place a corresponding policy element within the <outbound> section element.
    - To add a policy, place the cursor at the desired insertion point and select a policy from the sidebar.
    - To remove a policy, delete the corresponding policy statement from the policy document.
    - Position the <base> element within a section element to inherit all policies from the corresponding section element in the enclosing scope.
    - Remove the <base> element to prevent inheriting policies from the corresponding section element in the enclosing scope.
    - Policies are applied in the order of their appearance, from the top down.
    - Comments within policy elements are not supported and may disappear. Place your comments between policy elements or at a higher level scope.
-->
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <check-header name="X-Azure-FDID" failed-check-httpcode="401" failed-check-error-message="Not authorized" ignore-case="false">
            <value>aaabbbbccc</value>
        </check-header>
        <ip-filter action="allow">
            <address-range from="add1" to="add2" />
        </ip-filter>
        <set-variable name="backendUrlA" value="url1" />
        <!-- [A] Subscription 1: location East -->
        <set-variable name="backendUrlB" value="url2" />
        <!-- [B] Subscription 1: location East -->
        <set-variable name="backendA-apiKey" value="{{backendA-apiKey}}" />
        <set-variable name="backendB-apiKey" value="{{backendB-apiKey}}" />
        <!-- Load balancing logic -->
        <choose>
            <when condition="@((int)context.Request.Url.Path.IndexOf("/gpt-35-turbo") != -1)">
                <!-- Pool 1: GPT3.5 Turbo and GPT3.5 Turbo 16K -->
                <!-- Load balancing logic for gpt-35-turbo models -->
                <cache-lookup-value key="pool1Index" default-value="@((int)0)" variable-name="pool1Index" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@( (int)context.Variables["pool1Index"] == 0 )">
                        <set-variable name="selectedBackend" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendUrlA"])" />
                        <set-variable name="selectedBackendKey" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendA-apiKey"])" />
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <set-variable name="selectedBackend" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendUrlB"])" />
                        <set-variable name="selectedBackendKey" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendB-apiKey"])" />
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
                <!-- Increment the pool1Index and reset to 0 when it reaches the end -->
                <set-variable name="pool1Index" value="@((int)context.Variables["pool1Index"] == 1 ? 0 : (int)context.Variables["pool1Index"] + 1)" />
                <cache-store-value key="pool1Index" value="@((int)context.Variables["pool1Index"])" duration="1440" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@((int)context.Request.Url.Path.IndexOf("/text-embedding-ada-002") != -1)">
                <!-- Pool 2: Embedding ADA-002 -->
                <!-- Load balancing logic for text-embedding-ada-002 model -->
                <cache-lookup-value key="pool2Index" default-value="@((int)0)" variable-name="pool2Index" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@( (int)context.Variables["pool2Index"] == 0 )">
                        <set-variable name="selectedBackend" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendUrlA"])" />
                        <set-variable name="selectedBackendKey" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendA-apiKey"])" />
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <set-variable name="selectedBackend" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendUrlB"])" />
                        <set-variable name="selectedBackendKey" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendB-apiKey"])" />
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
                <!-- Increment the pool2Index and reset to 0 when it reaches the end -->
                <set-variable name="pool2Index" value="@((int)context.Variables["pool2Index"] == 1 ? 0 : (int)context.Variables["pool2Index"] + 1)" />
                <cache-store-value key="pool2Index" value="@((int)context.Variables["pool2Index"])" duration="1440" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <!-- Direct to Pool 3: General -->
                <set-variable name="selectedBackend" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendUrlA"])" />
                <set-variable name="selectedBackendKey" value="@((string)context.Variables["backendA-apiKey"])" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <set-backend-service base-url="@((string)context.Variables["selectedBackend"])" />
        <set-header name="api-key" exists-action="override">
            <value>@((string)context.Variables["selectedBackendKey"])</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <!-- Add the selected backend URL to the response headers -->
        <set-header name="X-Selected-Backend" exists-action="override">
            <value>@((string)context.Variables["selectedBackend"])</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

'''

Comment: Can you share the code which you are tried and also the error message if you are getting any?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin - This is the code i am using for calling the openai function. 

` 
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_version = "2023-03-15-preview"
openai.api_base = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_BASE')
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

# # Init LLM and embeddings model
text_loader_kwargs={'autodetect_encoding': True}
openaichat = OpenAIChat(temperature=0, engine="gpt-35-turbo-16k")
`

Comment: And what is the error you facing?

Comment: There is no error. I need to figure out a way to connect my webapp using APIM to the OpenAI endpoint. I have defined policy in APIM to connect to the openAI endpoint. How can i connect the webapp (python code) to the APIM

Comment: can you share the policy which you have configured in apim?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin 
I can mail you the policy. - you can hit me up - farzad.avari@live.com

Comment: @FarzadAvari please share the policy here in comment or in question

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin , Updated the question with the policy